# Number of k-APs in Z/NZ?

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic-progressions

Let $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ be the module class of an integer $N$. Let $k$ be an integer and we may assume $N$ is much larger than $k$ to avoid some trivial case. If necessary, we can also assume $N$ is a prime.

A $k$-term arithmetic progression ($k$-AP) $K$ in $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ is a set of $k$ distinct numbers in $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ so that you can name them $a_1,a_2,...,a_k$ with $a_i\equiv a_1+(i-1)d$ (mod $N$) for some $d\in \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ and all $i=1,…,k$.

**Question:** how many $k$-APs in $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$?

To solve this question, my idea is to first consider how many $k$-AP contains a fix number $x$: there are $k$ ways to determine the place of $x$ in a $k$-AP, and then there are $N-1$ ways to determine the "common difference" $d$. Then we can determine a $k$-AP containing $x$. So by a double-counting argument, there are $k(N-1)N/k=N(N-1)$ many $k$-APs in total. While I am not sure if $k(N-1)$ overcounts.

Comment: Pls clarify: (1) You want $a_i = a_1 + (i-1)d \pmod N$, not $\pmod d$, right?  If so pls fix your typo.  (2) Are you talking about a _sequence_ $(a_1, \dots, a_k)$, or are you really talking about a set?  A set makes not much sense in this context.  (3) It should be allowed that some $a_i = a_j$, right?

Comment: Alternatively, if you really mean a _set_, then the problem is more complex.  Given a $k$-sized set, the elements are unordered (coz it's a set), so how do you even tell if it is an AP?  Off the top of my head, I cannot think of some method substantially better than exhaustive testing.

Comment: Yes, it is mod N, apparently. The definition is for a $k$-set and it is valid: you just name the elements and if they satisfy the relation, then they form a k-AP.

Comment: The set doesn't have an order. You could ask for there to exist an ordering on that set and a $d$ such that the formula holds, but you can't demand that just on the set itself. If you mean for it to be valid, you are missing an existential over all possible ways to name the elements.

Comment: OK. I edited the question to make it more explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the edits.  Your original answer $k(N-1)N/k = N(N-1)$ is trying to count sequences, not sets.  (And when $N$ is not prime, it isn't fully correct if you restrict the sequence to have $k$ distinct elements.  See the answer by Carl Schildkraut.)  I still can't think of a good way to decide if a $k$-sized set is an AP, let alone count all such sets.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there. I'll work with a slightly simpler phrasing of your argument: there are $N$ ways to choose the first element $a_1$ (it may be any element of $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$), and there are $N-1$ ways to choose the difference (since it cannot be $0$).

However, are all differences possible? What if $N=4$, $d=2$, and $k=3$? Then, the terms are $\{a_1,a_1+2,a_1+4\}$, but $a_1+4=a_1$ in $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$. If $N$ is prime, then this issue doesn't arise for $k<N$, as for any $d\in\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$ nonzero, the terms $\{a_1,a_1+d,\dots,a_1+(k-1)d\}$ are distinct. However, for $N$ composite, you need to remove every $d$ for which $jd\equiv 0\pmod N$ for some $1<j<k$, i.e. those $1\leq d\leq N-1$ for which
$$\frac Nk<\gcd(d,N).$$
I don't think there's an explicit form for the number of such $d$, but you can count them for any given $N$ and $k$ if you'd like, and then multiply by $N$ to get the number of arithmetic progressions. (Again, if $N$ is prime, then the answer is what you got: $N(N-1)$.)

Comment: I think $N(N-1)$ is not the right answer: for $k=3$, we have $(a_1,d):=\{a_1, a_1+d, a_1+2d\}$, which is same as $(a_1+2d,-d)=(a_1+2d, N-d)$.